# Copy the values only between worksheets

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I am using this line to copy some sheets between two workbooks

```
shtSummary.Copy after:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)
```

but it copys the equations not the values so it result to empty cells in `wbNew` Workbook

How can I copy the values only between them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible when copying sheets.

But you could try something like this:

```
Dim destWs As Worksheet
Dim AddressStr As String

AddressStr = shtSummary.UsedRange.Address

With wbNew
    Set destWs = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
End With

destWs.Name = shtSummary.Name
destWs.Range(AddressStr).Value = shtSummary.Range(AddressStr).Value
```